# Display JFreeChart bar chart on Thymeleaf template

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jfreechart

New to both Thymeleaf and JFreechart. I have to display multiple bar charts on one html page. From research into how to get this done I found an example using Thymeleaf, as below:

```
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(pdSet, "Test Pie Chart using JFreeChart");

    try{
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), chart, 750, 400);
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I need to be able to pass the rendered chart to the model to be able to embed into the html as an image. I tried to pass this as a byte array, but with no success.
Controller code :

```
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(null, null, null, bardataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
    File file = new File("barchart.jpg");

    try {
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(filename), chart, 800, 100);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    if (clientList != null){
        model.addAttribute("chart", chart);
    }
```

chart.html:

```
    <div>
        <p> Bar Graph</p>
        <div>
            <img th:src="@{~/chart}" width="1000"/>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The above implementation from an example I came across...
Running this with Spring-boot 1.4.3 with its related dependencies for MVC, Thymeleaf, Security and JPA on Java jdk1.8.0_111.

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to put the chart on the model.  You want to write a servlet that returns a jpg image of the chart and then have the image src point at that servlet.

If you are dead set with having the chart on the model, you're going to have to encode the byte array as a base64 string and then do something like this:

`<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,BASE64ENCODEDSTRINGHERE" />`